# How to implement a Mesh network in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, offline, mesh-network, google-nearby-connections

Working on a project that should share data among 4+ devices offline. Using Google Nearby connection, we are able to establish a connection between devices via P2P-STAR topology. But what we really need is to have all devices receive and send data to all connected devices(M-N Connection).

After doing a research, Google Nearby API doesn't support mesh network so we have to build one on top of that API. But we are not able to find a good example to start with.

Any suggestion that can point us to that would be appreciated.

Comment: make it by bridgefy app.....(messages only)
make it by serval app.....(voice + messaging )

Answer (score 1):

There is [Bluetooth mesh](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Low-power-short-range-wireless/Bluetooth-mesh), but this is rather for BLE beacons.

There's also [Wi-Fi Direct](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct), which is not mesh networking.

Comment: Connection should be established and data should be sent and received among all devices  OFFLINE. We need to send data immediately after registration one after the other without requesting a connection everytime. So WIFI-Direct is not the best approach in our case.

Answer (score 1):

WiFi direct can be used for Mesh networking because each node can act both as an WiFi access point for others and as a WiFi station (client) itself. The tricky part is that each device as a group owner will be assigned the IP 192.168.49.1, so you get an IP address conflict. The workaround is to use the IPv6 link local addresses to transfer data:

```
val ssid = group?.networkName
val passphrase = group?.passphrase
val interfaceName = group?.`interface`
val linkInterface = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces().toList()
            .firstOrNull {
                it.name == interfaceName
            }

val linkLocalAddr = linkInterface?.inetAddresses?.toList()
            ?.firstOrNull { it.isLinkLocalAddress && it is Inet6Address } as? Inet6Address
```

Each node can then relay data to/from other nodes over multiple hops.

The device connecting would need to know the LinkLocal IP address of the other node before connecting to the access point; this can be done via QR code and/or Bluetooth Low Energy advertising.

Some Android 12+ devices support [Access Point-Station Concurrency](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#isStaApConcurrencySupported()). On those devices it is possible to run a [Local-only Hotspot](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/localonlyhotspot) and simultaneously connect to another access point as a station (client). The IP range of the Local-only Hotspot is randomized, so it is unlikely that two neighbor nodes will have an IP address conflict.

There is now an open-source library with an initial implementation of a Mesh Network over WiFi (disclaimer: I am the author of that library):

https://www.github.com/UstadMobile/Meshrabiya